# AFINN sentiment analysis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, lexicon

I want to understand the afinn code

```
from afinn import Afinn
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import textwrap
afinn = Afinn()
sentences = (" ".join(wordlist) for wordlist in gutenberg.sents('austen-sense.txt'))
scored_sentences = ((afinn.score(sent), sent) for sent in sentences)
sorted_sentences = sorted(scored_sentences)
print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(sorted_sentences[0][1], 70)))
```

output :
To attach myself to your sister , therefore , was not a thing to be
thought of ;-- and with a meanness , selfishness , cruelty -- which no
indignant , no contemptuous look , even of yours , Miss Dashwood , can
ever reprobate too much -- I was acting in this manner , trying to
engage her regard , without a thought of returning it .-- But one
thing may be said for me : even in that horrid state of selfish vanity
, I did not know the extent of the injury I meditated , because I did
not THEN know what it was to love .

Answer (score 1):

**Line 1**

Importing the library

**Line 2**

Imports the Gutenberg library from NLTK.

**Line 3**

Importing textwrap

**Line 4**

Instantiates an Afinn object.

**Line 5**

`gutenberg.sents('austen-sense.txt')` is a list of lists. `gutenberg.sents()` returns the given file(s) as a list of sentences or utterances, each encoded as a list of word strings. For example: `gutenberg.sents('austen-sense.txt')[2]`, which is the first actual sentence in *Sense and Sensibility*, is this:

```
['The', 'family', 'of', 'Dashwood', 'had', 'long', 'been', 'settled', 'in', 'Sussex', '.']
```

Afinn is a wordlist-based approach for sentiment analysis so you need a list, so that's why `(" ".join(wordlist) for wordlist in gutenberg.sents('austen-sense.txt'))` is used to take each wordlist and recreating sentences. It's also why there are spaces before punctuation. After the join, it becomes:

```
['The family of Dashwood had long been settled in Sussex .']
```

**Line 6**

Line 6 creates a list of tuples, with the first item of each tuple being the sentiment score given by Afinn and the second being the sentence.

`(afinn.score(sent))` gives the sentiment score for the wordlist 'sent'. The score for the wordlist in the example you gave is is -18.0. The score for the worldlist I gave is 0.0. For each list item in sentences (sent), a sentiment score is derived `(afinn.score(sent))` and paired with the sentence (sent).

**Line 7**

Line 7 sorts the 'scored_sentences' list with [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) by the first item in each tuple in ascending order.

**Line 8**

The print statement uses [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/textwrap.html) to display 70 characters per line. Textwrap will create a list of lines, so the join happens with a line break "\n". It's showing the first sentence in the sorted list, so this is the sentence with the highest score.

Without the join, `textwrap.wrap(sorted_sentences[0][1], 70)` looks like this:

```
['To attach myself to your sister , therefore , was not a thing to be',
 'thought of ;-- and with a meanness , selfishness , cruelty -- which no',
 'indignant , no contemptuous look , even of yours , Miss Dashwood , can',
 'ever reprobate too much -- I was acting in this manner , trying to',
 'engage her regard , without a thought of returning it .-- But one',
 'thing may be said for me : even in that horrid state of selfish vanity',
 ', I did not know the extent of the injury I meditated , because I did',
 'not THEN know what it was to love .']
```